# Foundation 6 Disable Accordion Item

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'd like to disable one item in a Foundation 6 accordion widget. That means if it's clicked/toggled, its contents should not drop down, and the title element should not change in any way (such as the small plus icon changing to a minus icon). I've found several answers for this questions, but nothing works 100%.

#### HTML

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
    <li class="accordion-item disabled">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">My Title</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
            <p>Hello, this is some content.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!--more items-->
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.accordion').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).find('div.accordion-content').hide();
    }
});
```

The code above partially works. If the accordion item is clicked, nothing happens. Great! But if it's double-clicked, the dropdown opens. Bad (it even snaps closed if clicked again). I tried adding a dblclick event to the binding, but it has no effect. If I remove the following line of code;

```
$(this).removeClass('is-active');
```

double-clicking no longer opens the item. But the aria attributes now all change, and the small title icon changes from plus to minus, indicating the accordion item is now open. This is not an acceptable solution.

I've tried messing around with the accordion API, but nothing seems to stop this from responding to double-click events. Interestingly, there is absolutely no double-click event anywhere triggering this. Plus, if I add an event listener breakpoint, then continue after the break, the item behaves itself, and no longer opens on a double-click. How is this happening?